# Toggle focus between monitors in windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm looking for a hotkey to toggle focus between two extended monitors on windows 10.  This means, if I have multiple windows open on each I can jump between the top window on either monitor with a single keystroke, regardless of when I last focused on it (this is why Alt+Tab is not the same thing).  I had this configured on KDE/Kubuntu and it was indespensible but circumstances require that I use windows at present.  Anyone know how to do this?

Edit: This is not the same as what win+shift+right-arrow does, which moves windows between screens.  I want to hop between the windows at the top of either screen while leaving them in their current locations.